# Как передать значение из JS в переменную PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет! Стоит задача, с которой пока справиться не смог. Есть:

```
document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML = rezultatRadio + totalPrice;
```

что мне нужно сделать (как я понимаю, нужно передать значение)

```
'product-price'
```

из

```
document.getElementById('product-price').innerHTML
```

в php-переменную, типа

```
$product_price
```

Выводить на этой же странице результат получается вот так:

```
<output id="product-price"></output>
```

И нужно этот же результат передать функцией mail(), и скорее всего переменной или сессией PHP, но решение пока не нарыл... Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

```
var varName = 'asd';     
$.post('/server/url', {myVar:varName});

<?
$product_price = floatVal($_POST['myVar']);
```

Comment: **Павел Вершинин**, а как это осуществить с моим кодом????   Все же действия происходят на одной странице order.php. На ней отображается и сам заказ, и изменение суммы учитывая выбранный тип доставки и отправка заказа на почту.....